# How to extract aarch64 vmlinuz gzip image?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am trying to PXE boot Ubuntu 20.04 aarch64 on the pi 4b but I am stuck at the point where I need to extract the kernel image vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi. I tried to zcat and pipe it out but I ended up with an empty file. I have also tried the extract-vmlinuz script but apparently that only works with x86-x64 kernels. Any idea? Thanks

```
vswitch0:~$ sudo file /var/tftpboot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi
/var/tftpboot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 23814656
vswitch0:~$
```

Comment: It's gzip compressed, have you not tried using the dd utility with gunzip to get the decompressed image? Or something like  'gzip -dc /var/tftpboot/file | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk# bs=1m' to flash it to something you can boot from?

Comment: zcat should work - exactly how have you executed zcat - perhaps you did it wrong

Comment: gzip -dc /mnt/cdrom/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1028-raspi | dd of=lol did work. Thanks